# What's the purpose of the generated "ormlite_config.txt" file for OrmLite?

Tags: android, ormlite

OrmLite creates this generated file, and the instructions say to use it in the CTOR.

However, we still need to create all the tables and set how to upgrade the database by ourselves, as shown in [**the instructions**](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/doc-files/ormlite_4.html#Use-With-Android) and on the [**sample app**](https://github.com/j256/ormlite-examples/blob/master/android/HelloAndroid/src/com/example/helloandroid/DatabaseHelper.java) .

My question is: why do we need this file? It seems that the app works fine even without it.
Shouldn't it be used in order to automatically create/modify the needed tables?

Sorry for not finding it, as it's quite hard to navigate in the OrmLite website.

Comment: Sorry I don't even remember this question. I hope it will help others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> why do we need this [ormlite_config.txt] file?

This can be found by looking at the [Android documentation](http://ormlite.com/docs/table-config).  To quote:

> For some time we have been struggling with DAO startup [performance]... Turns out that one of the major culprits is some ugly code down in the Android OS [annotations].
>
> ... ORMLite supports the loading of the data configurations from a text configuration file. When a DAO is created, these configurations will be used, removing the need for any annotation method calls entirely.

The config file configures the entities used in your code.  It does not automate the creation of tables or DAO classes however.  Once you have the entities loaded, it is very easy to use the `TableUtils` class to create the tables, etc..

---

I spend a *huge* amount of time on the ORMLite documentation and still get folks that say the following.  Depressing.  I would be happy to take into account specific recommendations on how to improve the site.

> Sorry for not finding it, as it's quite hard to navigate in the OrmLite website.

You could have found this in the documentation by looking in the [online documentation](http://ormlite.com/docs/ormlite.html) for:

- config file for tables
- android performance
- database config file

Or you could have looked in the table of contents for [*"Using Table Config File"*](http://ormlite.com/docs/table-config).

Comment: What does it mean that it "configures the entities used in your code"? What does it do to them? And how come the app seems to work fine without me using the file in the CTOR? Also, are you responsible for OrmLite? I've tried to contact the creator of the library, but I didn't get an answer. I wanted to ask there how can I make it support JDK 1.7, as it seems to have problems with using special features of it.

Comment: It stores the field information for each of the database entities.  Take a look at the config file for details.  It will work without the config file which is just used to improve performance.  I am the ORMLite author.

Comment: So the file is used for performance and that's it? Also, can you please make the library support JDK 1.7 for Android?

Comment: The only thing that threw me for a loop was the date **As of 9/2011, this is one of the newest parts of ORMLite so we most likely will be improving it. Feedback is welcome.** I found this StackOverflow question because I wondered whether, 3 years on, performance was still an issue.

Comment: +1 for that question. Are this performance issues still a thing? If yes, how are this performance issues still a thing?

Comment: This was an issue with the underlying Android OS.  Believe me I would have fixed it if I had the power.  I think it has been fixed as of Android 11 however.

Comment: @Gray, we are using a custom sqlite ORM on our company, to solve the issue with annotation processing we are using a static HashMap to keep the list of database entities. So my suggestion for you is, cant you get the info you want if the developer gave you list of entity classes instead of a text file that contains entity class desc? Other than that is very cool lib.

Comment: @Gray I seen here there is a java script to auto generate the config file:https://horaceheaven.com/android-ormlite-tutorial/. But what if I update my model classes do I need to rerun the script and update my config file?

Comment: If you change the fields or types or anything then yes @DegenSharew.

Comment: @Gray thanks for the details on this. If we're using OrmLite nowadays with a `minSdkVersion` greater than 11, is it still advised to use the `ormlite_config.txt` file?

Comment: I don't know actually @ankushg.  It would be interesting to do some performance runs with and without it to see how your application performs.